# Problem with Swift Package Manager - module map should be inside "Include" directory

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

This is my Package.swift file:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "MyProject",
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/AlwaysRightInstitute/cows.git",
                 from: "1.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/NozeIO/MicroExpress.git",
                 .branch("branches/swift-nio-lib"))
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages which this package depends on.
        .target(name: "Demo",
                dependencies: [
                    "cows", "MicroExpress"
            ],
                path: ".")

    ]
)
```

I've already initialised the Package correctly (I think) and the git repos are fetched (using "Swift package fetch/resolve")

Now i'm trying to "Swift build" but I get the follosing error:

```
'MyTarget' /Users/nimrodshai/Documents/MyProject: error: package has unsupported layout; modulemap '/Users/nimrodshai/Documents/MyProject/Pods/FirebaseCrash/Frameworks/FirebaseCrash.framework/Modules/module.modulemap' should be inside the 'include' directory
```

Anyone has any idea how do I solve this?

Edit:
I've trying uninstalling everything from the Pod file (including firebase) and then build. This is what i'm getting:

```
'Toky' /Users/nimrodshai/Documents/TOKY-TOY: error: target at '/Users/nimrodshai/Documents/TOKY-TOY' contains mixed language source files; feature not supported
```

Comment: You can try removing the `path` component of your target

Comment: I get: "could not find target(s): Demo; use the 'path' property in the Swift 4 manifest to set a custom target path"

Comment: What's your directory structure?

Comment: Which directory do u mean? The Package.swift is in the root folder

Comment: For example, if you run `swift package init` in an empty directory, the directory structure will be this: https://jsbin.com/padexodixe/edit?output

Comment: My Package.swift file sits exactly where my xcworkspace file sits.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know

Answer (score 1):

Try using the documentation found [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/PackageDescriptionV4.md#targets) for `publicHeadersPath` for targets. It says:

> publicHeadersPath: This property defines the path to the directory containing public headers of a C target. This path is relative to the target path and default value of this property is include. Only valid for C family library targets.

You should be able to set that to the path to your module.modulemap and it will then be happy.

Comment: Ok, tried that, but due to the fact that I'm using firebase, and firebase has many folders and all of them contain C files, I need to enter all folders paths but I couldn't enter more than one (or else it gets angry )

Comment: If you specify one directory as a target can you build just that directory?

Comment: Having same issue with Firebase. There is no support for SPM with Firebase. Were you able to solve this? Seems the best solution is to add that support in Firebase but seems quite daunting since there are so many libraries. Since WWDC 2019, announced SPM-Xcode integration it seems like time is right. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2135

Comment: I was able to get this working by symlink-ing the public headers to a directory named "include". Not a perfect solution but is working for now and didn't require moving the existing headers.

Comment: Typo and broken link in the answer. Spelling `publicHeadersPath`. Link: https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/main/Documentation/PackageDescription.md